# Showing uniqueness in this ordinary differential equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:

$$f'' + \frac{\cosh(x)}{\sinh(x)} f' + \lambda f = 0$$

And I would like to show that if $f$ is a function defined on $[0; + \infty[$ with $f(0) = 1$ and $f'(0) = 0$ and for $x \in ]0; + \infty[$ it is solution of the differential equation then it is unique.

Usually one would use Cauchy-Lipschitz however the initial conditions are at $0$ and the differential equation is not really defined at $0$ because $\sinh(0) = 0$... But my intuition tells me that this should work out because we have $f'(0) = 0$ but I cannot seem to find a way to prove this properly.

Just to make things clear, I do not want the existence of a solution, only it's uniqueness.

Comment: Hint: Denote $g = f'$ and apply [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2976638/195378)